# How to change the value of a HTML Element using a bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, html, bookmarklet

I'm not very familiar with JS and I was wondering how I could edit an element of a website using a bookmarklet

I was trying to change the value of 58 in the following code:

```
<span class="rbx-text-navbar-right" id="nav-robux-amount">58</span>
```

Yet I had no luck, as I had used different information from different sites.

Could someone please help me? If I'm not being specific enough, please tell me.

Comment: Do you really need bookmarklet? If it is not repetitive action, consider usage of browser dev. console to make required html edits.

Answer (score 1):

Set the URL of the bookmarklet to:

`javascript:` (code)

in order to run JavaScript in a bookmarklet. In your case, you would want

`javascript:document.getElementById("nav-robux-amount").innerHTML="59";`

Replace 59 with your value. Then, whenever you click the bookmark the script should activate.

**Break-down**

1. `javascript:` indicates that we are executing a script.
2. `document.getElementById("nav-robux-amount")` selects the correct element to modify.
3. `.innerHTML` refers to the HTML code that is inside the element.
4. `="59";` completes the statement by changing .innerHTML to 59.

Comment: My original answer was actually incorrect. I have just edited it, so that instead of `.value` it is now `.innerHTML` which is the correct way to do it.